# OWIN Security Providers with Forms Authentication For OAuth

Tags: asp.net, security, oauth, asp.net-identity, owin

We have an existing Asp.Net Webforms application with Forms based authentication. Now, we need to integrate OAuth providers(Google,FB,LinkedIn) for authenticating users. Can we use Owin security [providers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/owin.security.providers) without disabling forms based authentication in Webforms application?
All articles on internet suggest to use owin cookie based authentication by disabling FBA modules. It will be a major work for us if need to remove FBA module for this at this time. Is there a way we could still use forms authentication and use the owin security providers only for OAuth?

Note:
We are aware about DotNetOpenAuth providers and it can satisfy our needs. But wanted to check if we can use owin security providers with forms authentication.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Bala